# A div position inside a div

Tags: css, html

Well I'd like that the [inner](http://jsbin.com/welcome/54029/edit) div to be at the bottom of the containing div.

I have try bottom:0px; but it dont work.

Comment: Add `position: absolute;` to both `divs`. As @Kevin Boucher suggested.

Comment: bborisovs : adding position:absolute to both divs probably wouldn't work (on a _simple_ structure).

Answer (score 3):

You need `position: absolute;` along with `bottom: 0;`. And you may need `position:relative;` on the outer-div (depending on your structure).